# Why can't I open this table in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I created a couple of tables procedurally via C# named something like `[MyTableOneCustom0]` and `[MyTableTwoCustom0]`. When I try to return all of the values from these tables via "Open Table" in MSSQL Server Management Studio, I receive the following error:

> Error Source:
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.DataTools
>
> Error Message: Exception has been
> thrown by the target of an invocation.

However, I can still bring up all of the data via a `SELECT *` statement.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on a similar post loacated at at [Egg Head Cafe](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30462589/exception-has-been-thrown.aspx), it looks like the Management Studio will thrown an exception if there are too many columns included explicitly in the query. Select * returns them implicitly, so there doesn't seem to be an issue.

I have over 800 columns in this table, so I'm sure this is the problem.

Comment: If you really need 800 columns you may consider using sparse columns (SQLServer 2008)

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to ask, but normally you would not want 800 or columns in a database, so why did you do this? Given how databases store information you are possibly creating many problems for yourself with a design like that in terms of data retrieval and storage. How many bytes of data woudl a full row have? You know there is a limit to the number of bytes of data that can be stored in a row. You could be setting yourself up for issues entering data when a row exceeds those limits. It might be best to break into separate tables even if there is a one-to-one relationship. Read in BOL about data pages and how data is stored to understand why this concerns me.